# Double status bar with PySide and QML on Nokia N9 harmattan

Tags: pyside, meego-harmattan

I'm trying to use PySide with QML on Nokia N9, and for some reason, my test app looks unlike the native N9 apps. For example, here I get a double status bar (they both react to tapping).

[image: Double status bar]

Here's the code for this:

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtDeclarative import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QDeclarativeView()
view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView.SizeViewToRootObject)
view.setSource('main.qml')
view.window().show()
app.exec_()
```

And the QML files:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.meego 1.1 

PageStackWindow {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    var pageComponent = Qt.createComponent("PageX.qml")
    pageStack.push(pageComponent)
  }
}
```

**PageX.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.meego 1.1

Page {
  id: pageOne
  Text {
    text: "Hello, this is page one"
  }
}
```

The file `main.qml` creates a `PageStackWindow`, and I suspect it's the `...Window` part that makes the phone render the status bar again, like it tries to add a status bar to each window created (and here, maybe we have a window inside a window?). Also, there's a space between the window and the toolbar. Can someone point to the right way of doing this? I just want to use normal Pages inside a PageStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "showStatusBar : false". 
I tryed your example on Qt Simulator, and it works without statusbar. I had a Meego - QML - PySide application, QML app worked without statusbar on Qt Simulator. But When I tryed it on android with Necessitas, I got same problem. After I use "showStatusBar : false" problem solved. Thank you, It is first time I ran my QML-Meego application on android after I saw your question :)

```
PageStackWindow {
  showStatusBar : false
  Component.onCompleted: {
    var pageComponent = Qt.createComponent("PageX.qml")
    pageStack.push(pageComponent)
  }
}
```

Comment: :) So PySide works on Android too. `showStatusBar: false` might make this double statusbar symptom go away, but I think there's a bigger problem beneath that... I'm trying with `ListView` and other things instead of `PageStackWindow` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am new to QML. You can try a different QML Harmattan example and try again with python using this `view.window().showFullScreen()` My application includes ListView and is based on an example application by Nokia Harmattan developer documentation site. First this is main.py for android:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# A simple PySide example

import sys
import os
import traceback

# log to file on Android

LOG_FOLDER = '/sdcard/'
fSock = open(os.path.join(LOG_FOLDER, 'pyside_example_log.txt'), 'w', 1)
rfSock = open(os.path.join(LOG_FOLDER, 'pyside_example_error_log.txt'), 'w', 1)
sys.stdout = fSock
sys.stderr = rfSock

print("** stdout diverted to file **")

# for some reason, the PySide bindings can't find the libshiboken.so and libshiboken,
# even though they are in a directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, resulting in errors like this:
#
# ImportError: Cannot load library: link_image[1965]:   157 could not load needed library
# 'libshiboken.so' for 'QtCore.so' (load_library[1120]: Library 'libshiboken.so' not found)
#
# if both are loaded to memory manually with ctypes, everything works fine
print('manual libshiboken.so and libpyside.so loading')
from ctypes import *
#PROJECT_FOLDER = '/data/data/org.modrana.PySideExample'

# PYSIDE_APPLICATION_FOLDER is set in main.h in the Example project
PROJECT_FOLDER = os.environ['PYSIDE_APPLICATION_FOLDER']
LIB_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_FOLDER, 'files/python/lib')
SHIBOKEN_SO = os.path.join(LIB_DIR, 'libshiboken.so')
PYSIDE_SO = os.path.join(LIB_DIR, 'libpyside.so')
print("path to libshiboken and libpyside:")
print(SHIBOKEN_SO)
print(PYSIDE_SO)
shibok = CDLL(SHIBOKEN_SO)
psde = CDLL(PYSIDE_SO)
print("manual loading done")

print("importing PySide")
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import QObject
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtDeclarative import *
print("PySide import done")

#print(os.environ)



# enable running this program from absolute path
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print("dir changed")

class PropertyExample(QObject):
  """
  Python property provider
  """
  def __init__(self):
    QObject.__init__(self)
    self.rootObject = None
    #NOTE: the root object is needed only by Python properties
    # that call QML code directly

  """@QtCore.Slot(result=str)
  def getDate(self):
    return str(datetime.datetime.now())"""

  """@QtCore.Slot(str)
  def notify(self, text):

    #NOTE: QML uses <br> instead of \n for linebreaks
    self.rootObject.notify(text)
"""


class ImagesFromPython(QDeclarativeImageProvider):
  """
  Image provider example
  """
  def __init__(self):
    # this image provider supports QImage,
    # as specified by the ImageType
    QDeclarativeImageProvider.__init__(self, QDeclarativeImageProvider.ImageType.Image)



def main():
  app = QApplication(sys.argv) # create the application
  view = QDeclarativeView() # create the declarative view
  # add Python properties to the
  # QML root context
  rc = view.rootContext()
  # add the example property
  property = PropertyExample()
  rc.setContextProperty("example", property)

  # register image providers
  # NOTE: the image provider name in the Image.source URL is automatically lower-cased !!


  # NOTE2: view.engine().addImageProvider("from_python", ImagesFromPython())
  # doesn't work for some reason


  view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView)
  view.setSource("main.qml")
  rootObject = view.rootObject()
  property.rootObject = rootObject

  #view.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_TITLE)
  # view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView)
  #view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView.SizeViewToRootObject)
  view.window().showFullScreen()
  # view.resize(480,854)
  #view.resize(854,480)
  view.show()
  app.exec_()



if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("__main__")
  fSock.flush()
  try:
    main()
  except Exception:
    fp = open(os.path.join(LOG_FOLDER, 'pyside_example_exception_log.txt'), 'w', 0)
    traceback.print_exc(file=fp)
    fp.flush()
    fp.close()
    traceback.print_exc(file=fSock)
    fSock.flush()
  rfSock.flush()
  rfSock.close()
  fSock.flush()
  fSock.close()
  exit(0)
```

And QML codes:

```
//main.qml
 import QtQuick 1.1
 import com.nokia.meego 1.1

 PageStackWindow {
     id: rootWindow
     property int pageMargin: 16

     // ListPage is shown when the application starts, it links to
     // the component specific pages
     initialPage: MainPage { }

     // These tools are shared by most sub-pages by assigning the
     // id to a tools property of a page
     ToolBarLayout {
         id: commonTools
         visible: false
         ToolIcon {
             iconId: "toolbar-back";
             onClicked: { myMenu.close(); pageStack.pop(); }
         }
         ToolIcon {
             iconId: "toolbar-view-menu";
             onClicked: (myMenu.status == DialogStatus.Closed) ? myMenu.open() : myMenu.close()
         }
     }
 }




//MainPage.qml
 import QtQuick 1.1
 import com.nokia.meego 1.1

 Page {
     id: listPage
     anchors.margins: rootWindow.pageMargin

     function openFile(file) {
         var component = Qt.createComponent(file)
         if (component.status == Component.Ready)
             pageStack.push(component);
         else
             console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
     }

     ListModel {
         id: pagesModel
         ListElement {
             page: "SimpleExamplesPage.qml"
             title: "Simple examples"
             subtitle: "Buttons, TextField, ToolBar and ViewMenu"
         }
         ListElement {
             page: "DialogsPage.qml"
             title: "Dialogs"
             subtitle: "How to use different dialogs"
         }
     }

     ListView {
         id: listView
         anchors.fill: parent
         model: pagesModel

         delegate:  Item {
             id: listItem
             height: 88
             width: parent.width

             BorderImage {
                 id: background
                 anchors.fill: parent
                 // Fill page borders
                 anchors.leftMargin: -listPage.anchors.leftMargin
                 anchors.rightMargin: -listPage.anchors.rightMargin
                 visible: mouseArea.pressed
                 source: "image://theme/meegotouch-list-background-pressed-center"
             }

             Row {
                 anchors.fill: parent

                 Column {
                     anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                     Label {
                         id: mainText
                         text: model.title
                         font.weight: Font.Bold
                         font.pixelSize: 26
                     }

                     Label {
                         id: subText
                         text: model.subtitle
                         font.weight: Font.Light
                         font.pixelSize: 22
                         color: "#cc6633"

                         visible: text != ""
                     }
                 }
             }

             Image {
                 source: "image://theme/icon-m-common-drilldown-arrow" + (theme.inverted ? "-inverse" : "")
                 anchors.right: parent.right;
                 anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
             }

             MouseArea {
                 id: mouseArea
                 anchors.fill: background
                 onClicked: {
                     listPage.openFile(page)
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     ScrollDecorator {
         flickableItem: listView
     }
 }




 //DialogsPage.qml
     import QtQuick 1.1
     import com.nokia.meego 1.1

     Page {
         id: root
         tools: tabTools
         anchors.margins: rootWindow.pageMargin

         QueryDialog {
             id: query

             icon: "image://theme/icon-l-contacts"
             titleText: "Query Dialog Example"
             message: "Press accept or reject button"
             acceptButtonText: "Accept"
             rejectButtonText: "Reject"
             onAccepted: labelQueryResult.text = "Result: Accepted";
             onRejected: labelQueryResult.text = "Result: Rejected";
         }

         SelectionDialog {
             id: singleSelectionDialog

             titleText: "Single Selection Dialog Header"
             selectedIndex: 1

             model: ListModel {
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #1" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #2" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #3" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #4" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #5" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #6" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #7" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #8" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #9" }
                 ListElement { name: "ListElement #10" }
             }
         }

     // Create page and buttons
     ScrollDecorator {
         flickableItem: container
     }

     Flickable {
         id: container

         x: 0 // we need to set the width and height
         y: 0
         width: root.width
         height: root.height
         contentWidth: dialogs.width
         contentHeight: dialogs.height

         flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
         pressDelay: 100

         Column {
             id: dialogs
             spacing: 24

             Row {
                 spacing: 32

                 Button {
                     text: "Query"
                     width: 200
                     onClicked: {
                         query.open();
                     }
                 }

                 Label {
                     id: labelQueryResult
                     text: "Result: N/A"
                 }
             }

             Row {
                 spacing: 32

                 Button {
                     text: "SingleSelection"
                     width: 200
                     onClicked: {
                         singleSelectionDialog.open();
                     }
                 }

                 Grid {
                     rows: screen.orientation == Screen.Landscape || screen.orientation == Screen.LandscapeInverted ? 1 : 2

                     Rectangle {
                         width: 200
                         height: 30
                         color: "white"

                         Text {
                             y: 10
                             anchors.centerIn: parent
                             text: "Selected:"
                             font.pixelSize: 15
                             font.bold: true
                         }
                     }

                     Rectangle {
                         width: 200
                         height: 30
                         color: "lightgray"

                         Text {
                             anchors.centerIn: parent
                             text: singleSelectionDialog.model.get(singleSelectionDialog.selectedIndex).name
                             font.pixelSize: 15
                             font.bold: true
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

             Row {
                 spacing: 32

                 Button {
                     text: "Color menu"
                     width: 200
                     onClicked: {
                         colorMenu.open();
                     }
                 }

                 Rectangle {
                     id : colorRect
                     width: 50; height: 50;
                     color : "black"

                     MouseArea {
                         anchors.fill: parent
                         onClicked: { colorMenu.open(); }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     ToolBarLayout {
         id: tabTools

         ToolIcon { iconId: "toolbar-back"; onClicked: { colorMenu.close(); pageStack.pop(); }  }
         ToolIcon { iconId: "toolbar-view-menu" ; onClicked: colorMenu.open(); }
     }

     Menu {
         id: colorMenu
         visualParent: pageStack

         MenuLayout {
             MenuItem {text: "Red"; onClicked: { colorRect.color = "darkred" } }
             MenuItem {text: "Green"; onClicked: { colorRect.color = "darkgreen" }}
             MenuItem {text: "Blue"; onClicked: { colorRect.color = "darkblue" }}
             MenuItem {text: "Yellow"; onClicked: { colorRect.color = "yellow" }}
         }
     }
 }
```